# SignalR Client Trigger Events

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm trying to replicate behavior like a client browser but in C# (Performance reason). What I'm trying to set out to achieve is that for every new events received, my program should trigger the server side (Hub) which would then notify the client. Rather than having a while loop which would repeatedly hit the hub method every time even if theres no messages, is there a way to treat it as a trigger/detection so that once message is detected then execute Hub method ? Hope this makes sense

Snapshot of Client code below:

```
IHubProxy _hub;
string url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
var connection = new HubConnection(url);
_hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("PersonHub");
connection.Start().Wait();

//client side method
_hub.On("checkedIn", x => Console.WriteLine(x));

Console.WriteLine("Enter Person Name");
var answer = Console.ReadLine();
while (true) // Better way doing this? trigger or detect new message?
{
    //server side method
    _hub.Invoke("GetByName", answer).Wait();
}
```

Snapshot of Hub code below:

```
[HubName("PersonHub")]
public class PersonHub: Hub
{
    public Person GetByName(string name)
    {
        //logic and etc ...

        Clients.All.checkedIn(name);
    }
}
```

By setting the while loop to true this means this will always call the server side method (Hub method) which I dont want to. If theres new events triggered then it should hit the hub method. Is there a way to somehow listen for new message but not to execute if no messages has been detected?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
    {
         _hub.Invoke("GetByName", line).Wait();
    }
```